# Sitecore first publication data, should I build that myself?

Tags: date, sitecore, publish

Does Sitecore store the date of first publication for an item? I haven't been able to find anything like that in the Sitecore docs, so I am guessing I will have to build something that responds to a publishing event like [this](http://www.bolaky.net/post/Programmatically-skip-publishing-of-item%28s%29-in-Sitecore.aspx), but I would like to be sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore stores only the Created Date and Last Changed date in the statistics section of an item. You are correct in your assumption, that to store and use something such as a First Published Date you would have to cook up a solution for it yourself.